# How to convert this sql joins/count statements in clean ruby ActiveRecord

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord, count, left-join

I'm trying to convert with no success my find_by_sql statement into a pure ActiveRecord query.
It is:

```
Corner.find_by_sql('SELECT corners.id, corners.name, count(members.*) FROM corners LEFT JOIN places ON corners.id = places.ubicacion_id LEFT JOIN members ON places.id = members.place_id GROUP BY corners.id,corners.name ORDER BY corners.name;')
```

nicely formatted, the sql expression would be:

```
SELECT corners.id,
       corners.name,
       count(members.*)
FROM corners
LEFT JOIN places ON corners.id = places.ubicacion_id
LEFT JOIN members ON places.id = members.place_id
GROUP BY corners.id,
         corners.name
ORDER BY corners.name;
```

In very old versions of ActiveRecord, my approach would be using the find :all and then passing a hash of options, but this way is deprecated:

```
Corner.find( :all,
             :joins  => "LEFT JOIN places ON corners.id = places.ubicacion_id",
             :joins  => "LEFT JOIN members ON places.id = members.place_id",
             :group  => "corners.id,corners.name",
             :order  => "corners.name",
             :select => "corners.id, corners.name, count(members.*)"
           )
```

Which one would be the best approach to rewrite in the ActiveRecord way the query? This last snippet works well, but it makes no difference on using it rather than the plain sql one:

```
Corner.joins("LEFT JOIN places ON corners.id = places.ubicacion_id").joins("LEFT JOIN members ON places.id = members.place_id").group("corners.id,corners.name").order("corners.name").select("corners.id, corners.name, count(members.*)")
```

Many thanks!

Comment: hi, Do you have something like models or anything, and please tell us what you need.. in laymen. thanx

Comment: Why the left joins? If a corner has places and members, you don't need them. If it has places with no members or no places, you'll get a row with nils and a false member count of 1. There is a better solution if the left joins aren't necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you probably want to set up some model relationships to make this more ActiveRecord-like.  You can find descriptions of how to do this in the [Active Record Associations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html) documentation.

Consider these relationships:

```
class Member < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :place
end

class Place < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :corner
  has_many :members
end

class Corner < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :places, foreign_key: "ubicacion_id"
end
```

Given those, you should be able to do something like this:

```
Corner.
  select("corners.id, corners.name, count(members.*)").
  joins(:places, :members).
  group("corners.id, corners.name").
  order("corners.name")
```

Each of the methods chained in the query will refine the query incrementally, much like building a native SQL statement.  You can find the official documentation for these methods in the [Active Record Query Interface](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html)

Comment: Nice Michael! So the type of join is taken from the model, and it's enough passing the symbol to the joins method. Didn't know that! I'm going to find if it's possible to replacebalso the count(members.*) by any other method, so the select would be also cleaner, but I'm not sure...

Comment: The models give you a way to describe the relationship, and that's used during querying.  It helps you build consistent and bulletproof queries, since you don't have to write the relationship again in SQL form.  What you see is all it takes to do a moderately complex query of 3 tables with grouping.  ActiveRecord makes it so simple and painless.